# Unity 5.1.1f1 stop working as soon as I build my project

Tags: xcode, macos, unity-game-engine

I am facing this problem after updating OSX to 10.11.4 and Xcode.
Before Xcode and unity was working fine. But now after latest update of OSX and Xcode. Unity stop working as soon as I try to get a build of my Project. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you update your OSX and Xcode, it is likely that Unity 5.1 does not support either the OS or Xcode version. Unity is always releasing patches to support the latest Xcode. I suggest you download the latest Unity version which is [Unity 5.4.0B17](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta). This will likely solve your problem.